# Error comparing and fetching records in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have this table

table1

```
---------------
nums          |   
---------------
1             |
2             |
8             |
32            | 
11            |
31            |
28            |
17            |
38            | 
14            | 
--------------
```

then I have this table

table2

```
--------------------
DRAWNUMBER|n1|n2|n3|
--------------------
39494     |2 |23|34|
28288     |8 |12|11|
23000     |11|32|20|
90000     |14|28|38|
30000     |22|18|11|
10000     |32|39|18|
-------------------
```

with this query I fetch the numbers of the main draw(Grouped)from table2

```
SELECT (" "||n1||"-"||n2||"-"||n3 )NUMBERS FROM(SELECT n1,n2,n3, max(DRAWNUMBER) FROM table2)
```

Results:

```
----------
NUMBERS  |   
---------|
14-28-38 |
----------
```

Now what I need to do is to bring in table 1 only the numbers that are in table 2.

With this query I try to make a comparison but I get all the numbers from table 2.

```
SELECT nums from table1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT (" "||n1||"-"||n2||"-"||n3)FROM(SELECT n1,n2,n3, max(DRAWNUMBER) FROM table2))
```

Results:

```
---------------
nums          |   
---------------
1             |
2             |
8             |
32            | 
11            |
31            |
28            |
17            |
38            | 
14            | 
--------------
```

Expected:

```
---------------
nums          |   
---------------
14            |
28            | 
38            | 
--------------
```

If instead I want to fetch the numbers from table1 that ARE NOT in table2 it simply returns empty.

```
SELECT nums from table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT (" "||n1||"-"||n2||"-"||n3)FROM(SELECT n1,n2,n3, max(DRAWNUMBER) FROM table2))
```

Results:

```
---------------
nums          |   
---------------
              | 
--------------
```

I don't know what is wrong with the query. I have already changed the EXISTS to = and I have also used operator <> but it does not meet my expectations. Thanks in advance.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `table1` to the query:

```
SELECT n1, n2, n3, MAX(DRAWNUMBER) FROM table2
```

that returns the numbers of your *main draw*:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT n1, n2, n3, MAX(DRAWNUMBER) FROM table2) t2
ON t1.nums IN (t2.n1, t2.n2, t2.n3)
ORDER BY t1.nums;
```

Or change `IN` to `NOT IN` to get the numbers from `table1` that are not returned by the query.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=70d4691d4f3c36606edd51c906f1c994).

Comment: Curious about SQLite (that I don't currently use). Does it accept a mix of aggregated and non-aggregated columns as MySQL used to accept?

Comment: That's great! it works @forpas Thank you so much. Just I don't understand why it needs an inner join to working. The sqlite doc it doesn't mention this. Whatever ..It works!

Comment: @TheImpaler yes, this is documented behavior: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html search for "bare columns".

Comment: You're right @forpas it does about you say. But when one uses EXISTS or NOT EXISTS just  it calls the another table's column without inner join.. at least that's what I've seen in many examples. Thank you

Comment: @forpas Excellent. Just read it and it behaves the same wat as the old MySQL engines.

Comment: @JuanPerez `EXISTS(SELECT (" "||n1||"-"||n2||"-"||n3)FROM(SELECT n1,n2,n3, max(DRAWNUMBER) FROM table2)` returns always TRUE (unless table2 is empty) because it checks if there exists at least one row in the resultset of that query. This is why you get all the rows.

Comment: @forpas I got it. Thank you so much !